# Plot a triple bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a csv that looks like this:

[image]

I want a plot that has the countries in the x axis, and for each country, 3 bars corresponding to those variables.

I'm trying the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = country, y = x48), fill = "Rent price for a 1 room apartment in the center") +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_bar(aes(y = x49, fill = "Rent price for a 1 room apartment outside the center"), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_bar(aes(y = x54, fill = "Average monthly salary"), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

But instead of getting what I want, I get the following plot:

[image]

It seems like an easy fix but I'm not managing to fix it.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%  
  pivot_longer(-country) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = country, y = value, fill = name) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]

From that, you could:

```
df %>%  
  pivot_longer(-country) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = country, y = value, fill = name) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  theme_light() + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Metric", 
                      labels = c("1 room in the center", 
                                 "1 room outside the center", 
                                 "Average Monthly Salary")) + 
  xlab("Country") + 
  ylab("USD")
```

[image]

Comment: It's great, the only issue I have with this now is that, I now want to display the average salary and only one of the rents (the selection is made through a shiny input). And I don't know how to change the code for it to display only salary and ONE of the 2 columns instead of both.